# Multi Threading in Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat6

I am having multi threading application. After every 2 mins 3 threads are activated and with the help of socket programming we are writing data from remote location. It is working fine. but as the time increase memory is also increase. and at one stage my application crash. I need to restart my apache tomcat server twise in a day. As per me memory in not releasing by the thread. I have try with making unused object null and also write system.gc(). but still problem not resolved.

Comment: `system.gc()` won't help if you application is maintaining strong references to objects...

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. If you're asking us to help you debug your code, it's awfully hard to debug code you can't see.

Comment: Try collecting and analysing a heap dump using [`visualvm`](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to run [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) or [Sonar](http://www.sonarqube.org/) against your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that you could have done to get this situation.  For example:

- Your threads may not always be terminating.
- If you are using a thread pool, you may be accumulating garbage via thread-locals.
- This could just be an "ordinary" Java memory leak; e.g. deliberately or accidentally accumulating lots of objects in a "global" data structure.

I'd recommend the following:

- Take a thread dump to see if you've got lots of stuck threads.
- Follow the normal procedure for checking for memory leaks in Java.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

> as per my case thread is not releasing memory after it terminates. any idea how to release memory from thread ?

The stack is automatically released when the thread terminates, and all significant fields of the `Thread` object itself are nulled, including the reference to the thread local map and the reference to the `Runnable` (if you supplied one).  This only leaves fields that you defined in a `Thread` subclass.  They will become unreachable if you get rid of your application's references to the thread object.

In other words, if the thread *has terminated* then the memory leak is an "ordinary" one caused by your application keeping references to things that it doesn't need any more.

But we can't really help you if you don't show us the code.

Comment: actualy i am new to thread.. can u plz tell me how to check whether thread is terminated or not ?

Comment: A thread terminates when either the `run()` method returns, or when it dies due to an unhandled exception.

Comment: as per my case thread is not releasing memory after it terminates. any idea how to release memory from thread ?

Comment: You need to explain what you're doing, your question is very vague